# Retrieving lost photos

Tags: icloud, photos, data-recovery

My daughter recently transferred photos from her iPhone to her MacBook. When they had transferred she deleted them from her phone.

The transferred photos are now neither on the phone nor the laptop.  I suppose that deleting them from her phone actually deleted them from all devices...?

Is there any way she can recover the lost photos?

Answer (score 2):

There is Apple support document [Delete photos on your iPhone or iPad](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205856) which among other things states:

> If you use iCloud Photos, and delete photos and videos from one device, the photos and videos will be deleted on your other devices.

and

> When you delete photos and videos, they go to your Recently Deleted album for 30 days. After 30 days, they'll be permanently deleted.

Comment: Thanks for this.  So... is the 'recently deleted' folder to look in on her icloud account?

Comment: No. On iPhone go to Photos then Albums and scroll to end. Last one should be Recently Deleted.